# How to return a Promise on a cloud function firestore query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Here is my firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newMatch = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const user1 = data.user1;
    const user1token = data.user1token;
    const user2name = data.user2name;
    const user2 = data.user2;
    const gender = data.gender;
    console.log("before query");
    const user1doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user1);
    user1doc.get().then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.get("fcmToken"));
        return null;
    })
```

the `user1doc.get()` line is giving me the following error:

```
  22:2  error  Expected catch() or return  promise/catch-or-return
```

How can I return a promise so I can log the `fcmToken` value? Or is there a way to do it without returning a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put a `return` in from of the line that `get()`s the data:

```
return user1doc.get().then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.get("fcmToken"));
    return null;
})
```

I highly recommend learning more about Promises and their role in Cloud Functions, for example by reading https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93.

Comment: Or by watching the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/!!